# Name from selected item tree control in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

How can I get name of selected item in tree control in AX?
Method tree.getSelection() return id not name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getSelection()` to get the ID of the selection, then `getItem()` to retrieve that selection. Then do what you want with it.

```
FormTreeItem            selectedItem;

selectedItem = tree.getItem(tree.getSelection());

info(selectedItem.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

FormTreeItem.Text()

See the form tutorial_Form_TreeControl > FormTreeControl > method selectionChanged()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formtreeitem.aspx

Comment: Is there a method text() for FormTreeControl not FormTreeItem?

Comment: Text() is for FormTreeItem only. see tutorial_Form_TreeControl, for example.